# I try to load loading my image but html is not loading it

Tags: python, html, windows, pycharm

I hitted a wall, i don't really understand why browser is not loading my images. the path is correct, i drag image in browser.

```
<div class="paveiksliukas">
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/wanma/Desktop/html_images/wall.jpeg" >
    <div></div>
</div>
```

and it opens OK, then i just copying address and placing it into my code, but it not loading. i would be grateful is someone could help me, i'm just a beginner.

I tried to do research on google, but nothing is helping, it loads from internet with .GIF tag, but it is not loading .JPEG from hard drive, not sure why because, the path seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

file:///C:/Users/wanma/Desktop/html_images/wall.jpeg path.

Copy the image in same directory as html.

Then just name in img src tag like this:

```
<img src="wall.jpeg" >
```

Comment: Can you post screen short of your browser and code?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is propably only the /// before the path, code below works for me just fine

```
<div class="paveiksliukas">
    <img src="file:C:\Users\Downloads/image.jpg" >
    <div></div>
</div>
```